# How To Implement a Buildless Pipeline in a TypeScript Monorepo

Tags: typescript, monorepo, tsc, tsx

suppose I have this monorepo:

```
/apps
/apps/app1
/apps/app1/src  (contains index.ts and many other files and subfolders here)
/apps/app1/tsconfig.json
/apps/app1/package.json
/apps/app2 
/apps/app2/src   (contains index.ts and many other files and subfolders here)
/apps/app2/tsconfig.json
/apps/app2/package.json
/common
/common/package1
/common/package1/src
/common/package1/src/utility1.ts
/common/package1/src/utility2.ts
/common/package1/tsconfig.json
/common/package1/package.json
/tsconfig.json
/package.json
```

and that I only need esm to work in it.

how can I have tsx, tsc or any other ts tool running one or more apps that use stuff from "common/*/src" ? Basically without having to build stuff from "common" into a dist folder.

So every time I do a change to files within `/common` they take effect immediately when I run an app in watch mode.

Comment: So do you basically want that `cd apps/app1 && tsx watch src/index.ts` to restart on `/common/package1/foo.ts` change if `foo.ts` is imported?

Comment: Or do you want `tsx src/index.ts` to work even if `/common` is not built (i.e. `/common` have no `.js` files, only `.ts` files)?

Comment: I call second "typescript-only package" (as opposed to cjs/module packages)

Answer (score 2):

I might be misunderstanding you. But I think you are looking for something like the pnpm workspaces feature: https://pnpm.io/workspaces
Not sure how this would work with other package managers.

I created an example here.
https://github.com/quentinkrammer/mono

Go in `mono/app1` and do `pnpm install`, `pnpm dev`

This image show the gist of it:
[image]

The App2 workspace gets linked to the node_modules folder of App1. If you make changes to App2, they immediately show up in App1. This works for type checking as well as HMR. (At least that's my understanding of how it works)

Hopefully this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

First of all in the root folder of your `monorepo`, try to run `npm init -y` to create a `package.json` file and install `TypeScript` and `ts-node` as `dev` dependencies by running `npm install --save-dev typescript ts-node`, then again in the root folder, create a `tsconfig.json` file with this content :

```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "module": "es2020",
       "resolveJsonModule": true,
       "esModuleInterop": true,
       "rootDir": ".",
       "outDir": "./dist"
     },
     "include": [
       "apps/*/src",
       "common/*/src"
     ]
   }
```

now in each app's folder (`/apps/app1` and `/apps/app2`), update the `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
   {
     "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
     "compilerOptions": {
       "outDir": "./dist",
       "rootDir": "./src",
       "jsx": "react-jsx"
     },
     "include": [
       "src"
     ]
   }
```

and in each app's folder(`/apps/app1` and `/apps/app2`), update the `package.json` and then try to run `npm start` to start the app in watch mode for each app's folder:

```
  {
     "scripts": {
       "start": "ts-node src/index.ts"
     }
   }
```

at the end,any changes made to the files within `/common` will take effect immediately when running the apps!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately on windows there is no easy support of folder links, without having to type some commands manually.

On Linux I can easily make entire folder from some other repo appear as part of current repo without building everything. This is the only approach that works easily as all sort of path mapping, aliases etc never work correctly. If they work correctly on web, you will have problems in unit testing and vise versa. Also path mappings might also break source maps leading to debugging nightmare.

However, it isn’t a recommended approach once the packages become large.

A real problem is import path mapping. All paths become relative and moving them becomes issue.

A separate package is recommended if it is to be shared between multiple apps. Reason being changes and unit tests could be abstracted to focus on component development.

A separate package will always have fully qualified module path vs relative path. That is easy to copy and manage multiple packages.

I don’t think monorepo is solution to all problems. Purpose of monorepo is to have less dependency for deployment. Mono repo should have a single build and deploy script. Dependent npm package can always be integrated in deployment in a single build/deploy script.

Components should exist outside of monorepo as the code base will grow you will realize that components will be used for many different monorepo.  For example you are building an accounting software for one client, the whole accounting should be a mono repo. And social network for another client. Both will have your reusable components as dependency coming from some registry.

Now making a single monorepo for all clients and all projects isn’t a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the apps to treat `common/package1` as a package, i.e. import from a Javascript module instead of raw Typescript files from src, then you have to build the package somehow - no way around it. From the apps perspective, this is the easiest way to consume `common/package1`, as they do not need to worry about the package's dependencies or build peculiarities.

Using [workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces) makes the process more easy. Just register the apps and the common package in the top-level package.json:

```json
{
  "workspaces": [
    "common/package1",
    "apps/app1",
    "apps/app2"
  ],
  ...
}
```

This will build the projects into the top-level node_modules folder, so that they are accessible to each other.

The `common/package1` has to be setup as a package and you still have to have a watcher running to build it on update:

```json
{
  "name": "common/package1",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc --watch"
  },
  "module": "dist/index.mjs",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  ...
}
```

(The example assumes you are using plain tsc and have it setup to build a single file module - let me know if you want an example of tsconfig or Rollup setup)

The upside is that you can now treat it as a regular dependency in the apps:

```json
{
  "name": "apps/app1",
  "dependencies": {
    "common/package1": "^1"
  },
  ...
}
```

If the OS allows the app's build tool to pick up on the change, it will rebuild automatically when `common/package1` is updated (i.e. its watcher runs). Should work nicely. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is called `going buildless`.

There are articles available on this topic, but, I will reference the `modern-web` getting started article, as our team is currently vending web components and leveraging their approach to a `buildless` pipeline in order to accomplish this behavior in a mono repo structure.

https://modern-web.dev/guides/going-buildless/getting-started/

**For example:**

This is our `main.js` for storybook setting up `@rollup`.

```js
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../packages/*/stories/*.stories.ts'],
  rollupConfig(config) {
    config.plugins.unshift(
      typescript(),
      nodeResolve(),
      commonjs({
        include: /node_modules/,
      }),
    );

    return config;
  },
};
```

And our `npm script` to run `storybook` via `web development server`... we are basically using `tsc` as a compile checker/linter

```json
"storybook": "tsc --noEmit && concurrently -k -r \"tsc --noEmit --watch --preserveWatchOutput\" \"wds -c .storybook/server.mjs\"",
```

The only time we compile to `dist` is to publish our `npm` packages. All `.ts` level changes are "hot compiled" on the fly and are reflected in storybook immediately. This is also true for any internal dependencies between packages.